# Dictionary.Exists Always False

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I cannot for the life of my figure out why my dictionary is always returning false.

Notes:

- I Debug.Printed the BuildVelocityLookup at lookup.Add and it is reading in the whole range.
- I Debug.Printed conUD and it is also holding the proper value.
- The conUD value exists in the 10th column of velocity.
- Values are strings, alpha numeric with no special characters.
- Values are unique, there are no duplicate values in the Scripting.Dictionary.

Any/All Help is greatly appreciated.

Top of Module:

```
Dim velocityLookup As Scripting.Dictionary
Const Velocity_Key_Col As Long = 10
Option Explicit
```

Build Dictionary Code:

```
Sub BuildVelocityLookup(target As Worksheet, keyCol As Long, lookup As Scripting.Dictionary)
    Set lookup = New Scripting.Dictionary
    With target
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Dim keys As Variant
        keys = .Range(.Cells(2, keyCol), .Cells(lastRow, keyCol)).Value
        Dim j As Long
        For j = LBound(keys) To UBound(keys)
            'Note that the row is offset from the array.
            lookup.Add keys(j, 1), j + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Main Code: See 'xxxxxxxxxx Line for first call on dictionary.

```
Sub Calculate_Click()

'******************* Insert a line to freeze screen here.

    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim wsQuantity As Worksheet
    Dim wsVelocity As Worksheet
    Dim wsParameters As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim lrMain As Long 'lr = last row
    Dim lrQuantity As Long
    Dim lrVelocity As Long
    Dim lrParameters As Long
    Dim lrData As Long
    Dim i As Long 'Row Counter

    'For Optimization Testing Only.
    Dim MainTimer As Double
    MainTimer = Timer

    Set wsMain = Worksheets("Main Tab")
    Set wsQuantity = Worksheets("Quantity Available")
    Set wsVelocity = Worksheets("Velocity")
    Set wsParameters = Worksheets("Parameters")
    Set wsData = Worksheets("Data Input by Account")

    lrMain = wsMain.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lrQuantity = wsQuantity.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lrVelocity = wsVelocity.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lrParameters = wsParameters.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lrData = wsData.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Dim calcWeek As Long
    calcWeek = wsParameters.Range("B3").Value

    For i = 2 To 5 'lrQuantity
        With wsQuantity
            .Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(i, 1) & .Cells(i, 2)
            .Cells(i, 6) = .Cells(i, 1) & UCase(.Cells(i, 2).Value) & .Cells(i, 3)
        End With
    Next i

    wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(2, 1), wsData.Cells(lrData, 4)).Sort _
    key1:=wsData.Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    Dim tempLookup As Variant
    For i = 2 To 5 'lrData
        tempLookup = Application.VLookup(wsData.Cells(i, 2), wsParameters.Range("Table5"), 2, False)
        If IsError(tempLookup) Then
            wsData.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Missing"
        Else
            wsData.Cells(i, 3).Value = tempLookup
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 2 To 5 'lrVelocity
        With wsVelocity
            .Cells(i, 10) = .Cells(i, 1) & .Cells(i, 4) & .Cells(i, 5) & .Cells(i, 9)
            .Cells(i, 10).Value = CStr(Trim(.Cells(i, 10).Value))
            .Cells(i, 11) = .Cells(i, 6)
            .Cells(i, 12) = .Cells(i, 7)
            .Cells(i, 13) = .Cells(i, 8)
            .Cells(i, 14) = .Cells(i, 3)
            .Cells(i, 22) = .Cells(i, 1) & .Cells(i, 9)
        End With
    Next i

    wsVelocity.Range(wsVelocity.Cells(2, 1), wsVelocity.Cells(lrVelocity, 10)).Sort _
    key1:=wsVelocity.Range("J2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

    BuildVelocityLookup wsVelocity, Velocity_Key_Col, velocityLookup

    Dim indexVelocity1 As Range
    Dim indexVelocity2 As Range
    Dim matchVelocity1 As Range
    Dim matchVelocity2 As Range

    With wsVelocity
        Set indexVelocity1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 7), .Cells(lrVelocity, 7))
        Set indexVelocity2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lrVelocity, 3))
        Set matchVelocity1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrVelocity, 1))
        Set matchVelocity2 = .Range(.Cells(2, 22), .Cells(lrVelocity, 22))
    End With

    Dim indexQuantity As Range
    Dim matchQuantity As Range
    With wsQuantity
        Set indexQuantity = .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(lrQuantity, 4))
        Set matchQuantity = .Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(lrQuantity, 6))
    End With

    Dim ShipMin As Long
    ShipMin = wsParameters.Cells(7, 2).Value

    wsMain.Activate
    With wsMain
        .Range(.Cells(2, 9), .Cells(lrMain, 20)).ClearContents
        .Range(.Cells(2, 22), .Cells(lrMain, 47)).ClearContents
    End With

    For i = 2 To lrMain
        With wsMain
            Dim conUD As String 'con=concatenate
            conUD = .Cells(i, 21) & .Cells(i, 4) & calcWeek
            Debug.Print conUD

            .Cells(i, 21) = .Cells(i, 5) & .Cells(i, 3)

            If .Cells(i, 8) <> 0 Then
                .Cells(i, 9) = .Cells(i, 6) / .Cells(i, 8)
            End If
 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            Dim velocityRow As Long
            If velocityLookup.Exists(conUD) Then
                velocityRow = velocityLookup.Item(conUD)
                tempLookup = wsVelocity.Cells(velocityRow, 11)
            End If
            .Cells(i, 10).Value = tempLookup

            tempLookup = wsVelocity.Cells(velocityRow, 14)
            .Cells(i, 11).Value = tempLookup

            If .Cells(i, 9) > .Cells(i, 11) Then
                .Cells(i, 12).Value = Round((.Cells(i, 6) / .Cells(i, 11)) / .Cells(i, 10), 0.1)
            End If

            If .Cells(i, 6) > 0 Then
                If .Cells(i, 12) <> "" Then
                    .Cells(i, 13).Value = .Cells(i, 12) - .Cells(i, 8)
                End If
            End If

            Dim conECD As String
            conECD = .Cells(i, 5) & .Cells(i, 3) & .Cells(i, 4) & calcWeek
            If velocityLookup.Exists(conECD) Then
            velocityRow = velocityLookup.Item(conECD)
            tempLookup = wsVelocity.Cells(velocityRow, 12)
            End If

            If .Cells(i, 13) <> "" Then
                If tempLookup <> 0 Then
                    .Cells(i, 14).Value = Int(.Cells(i, 13) / tempLookup)
                End If
            End If

            If velocityLookup.Exists(conECD) Then
                velocityRow = velocityLookup.Item(conECD)
                tempLookup = wsVelocity.Cells(velocityRow, 13)
            End If
            If .Cells(i, 14) > tempLookup Then
                If .Cells(i, 14) <> "" Then
                    .Cells(i, 15).Value = tempLookup
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(i, 15).Value = .Cells(i, 14).Value
            End If

            If .Cells(i, 14) = "" Then
                If .Cells(i, 11) = "" Then
                    .Cells(i, 26) = ""
                Else
                    .Cells(i, 26).Value = Round(.Cells(i, 14).Value * .Cells(i, 11).Value, 0)
                End If
            End If

            tempLookup = Application.Index(indexQuantity, Application.Match((.Cells(i, 21).Value & "LIBERTY") _
                , matchQuantity, False))
            .Cells(i, 24).Value = tempLookup

            .Cells(i, 18).Value = .Cells(i, 24) - Application.SumIf(.Range(.Cells(1, 21), .Cells(i, 21)), _
                .Cells(i, 21).Value, .Range(.Cells(1, 26), .Cells(i, 26)))

            If velocityLookup.Exists(conUD) Then
                velocityRow = velocityLookup.Item(conUD)
                tempLookup = wsVelocity.Cells(velocityRow, 13)
            End If
            If .Cells(i, 26) > tempLookup Then
                .Cells(i, 28).Value = tempLookup
            Else
                .Cells(i, 28).Value = .Cells(i, 26).Value
            End If

            If .Cells(i, 18).Value < 0 Then
                .Cells(i, 29).Value = "C"
                .Cells(i, 27).Value = ""
            Else
                .Cells(i, 27) = .Cells(i, 28)
            End If

        .Cells(i, 31).Value = Application.SumIf(.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrMain, 1)), _
            .Cells(i, 1).Value, .Range(.Cells(2, 27), .Cells(lrMain, 27)))

            If .Cells(i, 5) = "" Then
                .Cells(i, 35) = ""
            Else
                .Cells(i, 35).Value = Application.Index(indexVelocity1, _
                Application.Match(.Cells(i, 5), matchVelocity1, False))
            End If

            If .Cells(i, 6).Value = 0 Then
                .Cells(i, 44).Value = 0
            Else
                .Cells(i, 44).Value = Round(((((.Cells(i, 6).Value / .Cells(i, 11).Value) _
                    / .Cells(i, 10).Value) - .Cells(i, 8).Value) / .Cells(i, 35).Value), 0.1)
            End If

            If .Cells(i, 6).Value = 0 Then
                .Cells(i, 34).Value = 0
                .Cells(i, 33) = 0
            Else
                .Cells(i, 34).Value = Round(((((.Cells(i, 6) / .Cells(i, 11)) / _
                .Cells(i, 10)) - .Cells(i, 8)) / .Cells(i, 35)) * .Cells(i, 11), 0.1)
                If .Cells(i, 34) > 0 Then
                    .Cells(i, 33) = .Cells(i, 34)
                Else
                    .Cells(i, 33) = 0
                End If
            End If

            .Cells(i, 37) = 1 + calcWeek
            .Cells(i, 38) = .Cells(i, 5) & .Cells(i, 37)
            .Cells(i, 39).Value = Application.Index(indexVelocity2, _
                Application.Match(.Cells(i, 38), matchVelocity2, False))
            .Cells(i, 40) = Round(((((.Cells(i, 6) / .Cells(i, 11)) * .Cells(i, 39)) _
                - .Cells(i, 6)) - (.Cells(i, 8) - .Cells(i, 6))) / .Cells(i, 35), 0.1)

            If .Cells(i, 40) < 0 Then
                .Cells(i, 41) = 0
            Else
                .Cells(i, 41) = .Cells(i, 40)
            End If

            .Cells(i, 42) = .Cells(i, 41) - .Cells(i, 33)

            If .Cells(i, 11) < .Cells(1, 44) Then
                .Cells(i, 45) = 0
                .Cells(i, 32) = .Cells(i, 45)
            Else
                .Cells(i, 32) = Application.Max(.Cells(i, 33), .Cells(i, 41))
                If .Cells(i, 44) < 0 Then
                    .Cells(i, 45) = ""
                Else
                    .Cells(i, 45) = .Cells(i, 44)
                End If
            End If

            If .Cells(i, 31) < ShipMin Then
                .Cells(i, 47) = 0
            Else
                .Cells(i, 47) = .Cells(i, 27)
            End If

            .Cells(i, 46) = .Cells(i, 1) & .Cells(i, 22) & .Cells(i, 47)


        End With

        If (i Mod 100) = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Got to row "; i; " in "; Timer - MainTimer; " seconds."
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Dictionaries are case-sensitive -- could that be the problem? Also, note possible leading/trailing spaces, etc.

Comment: For debugging purposes you can create an array and set the array equal to Dictionary.Keys. This will show you all the keys within the dictionary. Same for Dictionary.Items. My best bet (assuming the dictionary is loading items in as expected) is that there is case sensitivity. The dictionary will look for exact match unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @DavidZemens  The cases match, leading and trailing spaces are taken care of during the data import.

Comment: Step through your code line-by-line, using F8 in debug mode. This is probably something you need to identify on your own, as we don't have your data to test with.

Comment: What should I look for when I step through? Everything runs fine, just on that first "If velocityLookup.Exists(conUD)" always shoots back FALSE and so it skips the rest. This is my first time using dictionaries so I wasn't sure if there was something I might not know to check. (For example I didn't know it was case sensitive).

Comment: When you get to that line (set a breakpoint on that line), examine the contents of your dictionary, and the value of your key/lookup in the Locals window of the VBE.

Comment: What's the best way to 'examine the contents of your dictionary' by doing a Debug.Print?

Comment: You can view the first 255 *keys* in the Locals window of the VBE. If you need to see more than that, then I think as Brandon mentions, declare a variant like `Dim dictVals` and then do `dictVals = velocityLookup.Keys()`, and you'll be able to see each of those in the Locals pane. Can do the same with the `.Items` if needed.

Comment: To bring up the Locals window in the VBE it's under View > Locals Window. If you're not also using the *Immediate* pane (you can enter simple statements and queries here), you can activate that from View menu as well.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't activated either of those. I don't see velocityLookup in the Locals window. That is probably the problem.

Comment: Can you screenshot what you do see in Locals?

Comment: velocityLookup is a module-level variable, so it might be nested under something like `Module1`, or is this a sheet/userform module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138751/discussion-between-emily-alden-and-david-zemens).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From chat we identified a capitalization error. You can avoid these (assuming they are false errors) by forcing a consistent case (either using `LCASE` or `UCASE` functions, a matter of personal preference just be consistent throughout!).

You can also make your dictionary case-insensitive at instantiation:

```
Set lookup = New Scripting.Dictionary
lookup.CompareMode = 1 'TextCompare
```

You have to do this prior to adding any items, though.

One thing you *might* also consider, not sure about the use-case here, is to wrap your `BuildVelocityLookup` procedure with some logic to avoid re-writing the dictionary every time the `Click` event fires.

```
Sub BuildVelocityLookup(target As Worksheet, keyCol As Long, lookup As Scripting.Dictionary)
    If Not lookup Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '## Get out of here if the dict is already instantiated
    Set lookup = New Scripting.Dictionary
    With target
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Dim keys As Variant
        keys = .Range(.Cells(2, keyCol), .Cells(lastRow, keyCol)).Value
        Dim j As Long
        For j = LBound(keys) To UBound(keys)
            'Note that the row is offset from the array.
            lookup.Add keys(j, 1), j + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

And also, since the entire purpose of `BuildVelocityLookup` is to merely instantiate your dictionary, you might consider changing it to a `Function`, which would be more standard use.

In general: *function* return values to objects/variables, whereas *subroutines* perform some action(s), modifying objects, environment, etc.  Passing objects `ByRef` allows a `Sub` to behave like a `Function`, but unless you have a specific reason for designing it this way, a Function is probably better:

```
Function BuildVelocityLookup(target As Worksheet, keyCol As Long) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim lookup as New Scripting.Dictionary
    With target
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Dim keys As Variant
        keys = .Range(.Cells(2, keyCol), .Cells(lastRow, keyCol)).Value
        Dim j As Long
        For j = LBound(keys) To UBound(keys)
            'Note that the row is offset from the array.
            lookup.Add keys(j, 1), j + 1
        Next
    End With
    Set BuildVelocityLookup = lookup
End Sub
```

And then call it like (omit the `If` condition if you don't mind re-writing the dict every time user clicks):

```
If velocityLookup Is Nothing Then
    Set velocityLookup = BuildVelocityLookup(wsVelocity, Velocity_Key_Col)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else still stuck on this error, i had been running into a similar issue but the cause was that i was adding a Range object to my dictionary rather than the Range.Value property.

e.g.

```
For Each part In Selection
    dict.Add part, part.Address
Next part

'this returns false
Debug.Print dict.Exists("some text in range")
```

but if i add the value property it works as expected:

```
For Each part In Selection
    Debug.Print part
    dict.Add part.Value, part.Address
Next part

'this returns true
Debug.Print dict.Exists("some text in range")
```